# Bind to DataContext of ItemsControl from within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I'm using an ItemsControl, boiled down, in this way:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="HomeItemTemplate">
    <UserControl Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeItemTemplate}" />
```

Now, the view this ItemsControl is placed in has a DataContext. In that DataContext I have my MyCommand. I have to use this ItemsControl in multiple places, so directly referencing to an ElementName within the DataTemplate is something I don't want to do.

I tried TemplatedParent and RelativeSource, different stuff, I don't know what exactly I should do. How would I have to write this so my UserControl can bind to the DataContext of the ItemsControl?

Comment: Is "MyCommand" always the same command?

Comment: Not necessarily. Also, I have other Properties I need to bind, this command is just an example.

Comment: Okay, then do your binding like `"{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"` (not tested, just from the back of my head; also note that this binding would not work if you use the datatemplate in any control which is not derived from ItemsControl...)

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. Someone told me it might be because the resources I'm in are outside the normal visual tree, not sure about that.

Comment: No, the datatemplate being in a resource dictionary is not the issue. If it still is not working, the issue is related to something else (resource dictionary might be a related side effect, then). There are different possibilities for failure, like the datacontext of the ItemsControl not being what you expect, the MyCommand property not being backed by a INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and being set after the binding has been established; just to name a few...

Comment: Not sure what changed. I tried what you said, didn't work, changed around some stuff (various, not sure what exactly I tried), tried your line again, it seemed to work :-/

Comment: Ok, As for a lack of a better way, and because your answer seemed to have helped me, if you put it into an answer form, I'll accept it!

Comment: Sorry, i did not see your comment until today, as i was 'offline' yesterday. However, better late than never - finally the answer is there.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a *DataTemplate*/*ItemTemplate* in a resource dictionary, you might want to use the `{RelativeSource FindAncestor}` binding mode to bind to properties of the parent *ItemsControl*:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="HomeItemTemplate">
    <UserControl Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```